# Ionic Capacitor Camera Delete Image

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

Im using the capacitor [camera](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/camera) api to get Images. Im just interested in the base64 encoded image data. So I don't need any image pathes. Im using the following code:

```
const image = await Camera.getPhoto({
    quality: 90,
    allowEditing: false,
    resultType: CameraResultType.Base64
});
```

I noticed the local "user data" increases by each image the user makes (tested on Android). The image gets stored somewhere (on Android its: "Android/data/com.mypackage/files/Pictures") I can't test it on iOS at the moment. I guess it behaves differently there.

Is there any good way to delete those image files?
I could get the image path if I change the resultType, read the image with the file api and convert it manually into base64 but it makes the resultType setting useless.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use Filesystem API to delete image temp when you're done in the image.

If you're using ionic native camera check here https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/camera/, it has a function called cleanup() - Remove intermediate image files that are kept in temporary storage after calling camera.getPicture. Applies only when the value of Camera.sourceType equals Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA and the Camera.destinationType equals Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the documentation says `cleanup()` is only for iOS.